# Getting a button to work in the list view

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android and my code has got a bit messy. I have successfully created a list view extended from item_layout.xml. When I click on the list view It works exactly how I want it. However in each item of the list view I have a button that when clicked I want the item of the list to delete.

When researching I have come across that you need to create a customer adapter to do this however I have come so far in the project that I wouldn't even know where to start.

This code it used successfully to when the list items are clicked it works. This is just put in the Main Activity class

```
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(
    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

        }
    }

);
```

I populate the list using this function just outside the main activity class. It is needed to be written like this as It gets the items from a database and has to be called depending on different circumstances

```
private void populatelistView() {
    Cursor res = userDb.getAllRows();
    String[] fromFeildnames = new String[]{ DatabaseUser.KEY_1, DatabaseUser.KEY_2};
    int[] toViewIds = new int[]{R.id.textViewNum, R.id.textViewItem};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor;
    myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_layout, res, fromFeildnames, toViewIds, 0);
    //ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);
    mylist.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);

}
```

I would like to be able to get the button on each items to work by not changing much of what I have already written. I have tried just using the following code. But because it is in a different xml layout it display an error of null reference towards the item button

```
delete.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
            ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
            final int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
);
```

Please could someone help me make the button work without changing much code or give me a step by step tutorial on how to add an adapter but make my populateListView function do the same thing.

Ps. I have looked at so many tutorials about list adapters but can't find ones that are for my specific need

Comment: did you try to access delete button in your SimpleCursorAdapter class?

Comment: This is actually the answer. Thank you so much, I would check it but its written as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: if u post your SimpleCursorAdapter code i also can help u :)